# jQuery plugin - for loop for settings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a jQuery plugin where the settings have the same name but a different number. So the script called in my HTML file looks like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').myPlugin({
      cName1 : 'First name here',
      cName2 : 'Second name in here',
      cName3 : 'Third name here',
    });
  });
</script>
```

There may be an indefinite amount of settings i.e. `cName18`
So in the actual plugin I want to loop through all instances with a for loop but using 'i' as part of the string instead of calling a part of an array. Something like this:

```
for (var i=1;i<20;i++) {
  var cName = settings.cName + i;
  if (cName) { cNameArray.push(cName); }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work though. Does anyone know how to use 'i' in a for loop like this?

Comment: I guess you realy need to learn about [Array objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need an array.

```
$('body').myPlugin({
  cNames: [
    'First name here', 
    'Second name in here', 
    'Third name here'
  ]
});
```

and a quick update based on the comment since you want descriptions as well:

```
$('body').myPlugin({
  cNames: [
    {
      name: 'First name here',
      description: 'First!'
    },
    {
      name: 'Second name in here',
      description: 'I am the second one!'
    },
    {
      name: 'Third name here',
      description: 'BRONZE BABY'
    }  
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks yeh this is a good solution. I didn't mention that each cName will also have a cDescription so didn't want to put them in arrays for that reason.

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for any number of fields you'd need.  You should be using an array for this task. You're just ending up with an array anyway.

Comment: Yes I see. This is probably a better way of doing it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
for (var i=1;i<20;i++) {
  var cName = settings['cName' + i];
  if (cName != undefined && cName != null) { cNameArray.push(cName); }
}
```

However, a way better idea would be to let the plugin accept an array of the "cNames", like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').myPlugin({
      names : ['First name here', 'Second name in here', 'Third name here']
    });
  });
```

Then, in the plugin, you can use simple $.each to loop through the array.

Comment: No that doesn't work. I think the issue is getting it to understand I want to add the 'i' on almost like creating a string so it'll output cName1, cName2 etc.

Comment: Cool yeh the array will work but not quite what I'm looking for because each cName will have a cDescription so I don't want really want them bunched up in arrays. I found a solution to my own question thogh - posted above

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my own question:

```
for (var i=1;i<20;i++) {
      var cName = 'cName' + i;
      if (settings[cName]) { cNameArray.push(cName); }
    }
```

Comment: The concept is different here. I've treated the 'cName' as a string in it's own variable, not as an object.

Comment: I had a typo there, cName instead of 'cName', but other than that, our two examples are pretty much the same. I don't see the "different concept" anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I've already accepted an answer. My original issue was understanding the way to mix the objects and strings to get the outcome I needed. Your original solution didn't bring any strings into the answer, which is essential to get it working.